# Support = 'None'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

Using the code below I get values for `precision`, `recall`, and `F scores` but I get `None` for `support`

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
ytrue = np.array(['1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1','1','1','0'])
ypred = np.array(['0', '0', '0', '1', '1','1','1','1','0'])
precision_recall_fscore_support(ytrue, ypred, average='weighted')
```

output:

```
(0.91666666666666663, 0.66666666666666663, 0.72820512820512828, None)
```

I checked http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html but I find it a bit unclear as to why it is `None`

Questions:

1. Why is `support` equal to `None` in my output?
2. How do I get a non-`None` output?

Comment: Can't really tell much what you're trying to achieve, but  you can follow the link to source on the link you've provided and get some insight for your problem [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L876).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is support equal to None in my output?

If a value for `average` is provided, `None` is returned for support

> How do I get a non-None output?

Don't provide a value for `average`. If you still want to use `weighted` and need the support, just do something like

```
> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
> np.sum(confusion_matrix(ytrue, ypred), axis=1)
array([1, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Support is not err... supported, while `average` is provided. Documentation is kinda cryptic on this, take a look at [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L1155)

Comment: seems to me the documentation is misleading